# gradle sonarqube plugin not uploading analysis report to sonarqube server

Tags: gradle, sonarqube-scan

Gradle sonarqube plugin is not uploading analysis report on subsequent runs on same branch
our application is gradle kotlin. On initial run of gradle sonarqube tasks, scan results are visible on SonarQube server UI. On subsequent runs results are not updated after source code changes are made to same branch.
SQ UI displays obsolete results from initial analysis and  does not reflect latest changes

Following are details

1. SonarQube gradle plugin: version 3.3
2. SonarQube server       : Community Edition Version 8.9.3(tried 9.2.4)
3. Gradle                 : 6.9
4. Kotlin                 : 1.4.20
5. JVM                    : 11.0.9.1(Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.9.1+1-LTS)
6. OS                     : Windows 10 10.0 amd64

gradle command:

```
gradle clean sonarqube 
-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 
-Dsonar.login=token 
-Dsonar.verbose=true
```

sonarqube entries in build.gradle

```json
classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
sonarqube >{
            properties {
              property 'sonar.projectKey', "mykey:myproj"
              property 'sonar.projectName', "myproj"
              property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
              property "sonar.sources", "src/main/kotlin"
              property 'sonar.language', 'kotlin'
       }<
}
```

There are no errors in logs. All directories created under projectdir/build/sonar/ after initial analysis are empty.

output from CE task

```json
{
      "task": {
       "id": "AX7CXu0VnYeriyF0iIMT",
       "type": "REPORT",
       "componentId": "AX6xHNHtvlM2NwXtAndE",
       "componentKey": "k:val",
       "componentName": "val",
       "componentQualifier": "TRK",
       "analysisId": "AX7CXv3BhrpCXzBkYf5n",
       "status": "SUCCESS",
       "submittedAt": "2022-02-03T19:35:08-0600",
       "submitterLogin": "admin",
       "startedAt": "2022-02-03T19:35:09-0600",
       "executedAt": "2022-02-03T19:35:28-0600",
       "executionTimeMs": 18532,
       "hasScannerContext": true,
       "warningCount": 0,
       "warnings": []
   }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm pretty sure that is a bug